# Input Element - Align Content that Overflows Left on Blur

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you have a text input of a certain length and you set the content in it longer than the area, how can you have the content always align left in the text box on blur? **Even if you manually go to the cell, scroll to the right side and then leave.**

```html
<input type="text" style="width:100px" value="356 Must Read Number Ave New York, NY">
```

You should always be able to read "365 Must ..." in the beginning of the input? text-align:left; doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    let el = document.querySelector("input") 
    el.addEventListener("focusout",function (e) {
        el.scroll(0,0)  //first one x-coord, second one y-coord
    })
```

```html
<input>
```

[Element.scroll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll) might be helpful

Comment: Can you retroactively scroll after input was already blurred? scroll(0,0) doesn't seem to do anything when I try on an element that is already out of focus

Comment: OK, this seems to work if you clear the value in the cell before you set it. Otherwise with existing values in place if you change the value it seems to do a weird thing in Firefox and scroll in the middle someplace.